# PIVOT using AVG not working correctly in my query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have following table and finding difficult to produce expected output. I have tried following query but it doesn't produce correct 'AVG' using 'PIVOT'. The average value should show in respective columns of category as per the output. In my below query it doesn't work

```
SELECT *
FROM (select     avg(hd.SCORE) over(partition by hd.org_id) Avg_Item
, hd.org_id,d.cateogory,hd.score FROM Category d JOIN Assign hd ON d.catid=hd.catid) first
PIVOT (
  AVG(score)
  FOR (cateogory)
  IN ('cat1' as "cat1",'cat2' as "cat2",'cat3' as "cat3",'cat4' as "cat4")
)PIV;
```

Sample Tables & Expected Output

```
Category table                     
-----------------------
catid  cateogory              

1      cat1
2      cat2
3      cat3
4      cat4
5      cat5


Assign table
--------------------------
Aid(pk)  catid(fk) pid Score org_id
1          1       1     98  1
2          1       2     99  1
3          1       3     100 1
4          2       4      12 4
5          2       8       78 5
6          5       9       98 6


org Table
-----------------------------
org_id org_name
1        ABC
2        CDE
3        FGH
4        Google
5        Yahoo
6        Facebook


Desired output
----------------------------------

org_name   cat1  cat2  cat3  cat4 cat5
 
ABC         99 
CDE               12     
FGH              
Google            78
Yahoo                              98
Facebook
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean - do you get an error, or wrong results? What data type is `score` - is it really stored as a string like `'98%'`, or as a number, as `98` or `0.98`?

Comment: @Alex Poole just number without %. I am removing %. When I run query it doesn't get the correct average in pivoted column. Wrong results getting in o/p

Comment: It seems to get the right numbers - maybe if you include the wrong result you are getting for that data in the question (and confirm you've got the `org_id` values right - so the numbers are against the right or names?) it might be clearer what you mean.

Comment: yes, My org_id was wrong in my table. My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `score` is actually a number, not a string like `98%`, then your current query seems to work, and (with `cat5` added) produces:

| AVG_ITEM | ORG_ID | cat1 | cat2 | cat3 | cat4 | cat5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 1 | 99 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 12 | 4 | *null* | 12 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 78 | 5 | *null* | 78 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 98 | 6 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 98 |

which seems right.

But you aren't using the analytic `avg_item` you calculate in your desired result, so you can remove that form the subquery. And you can outer join the result of the pivot to the `org` table to get the organisation names:

```
SELECT o.org_name, p.cat1, p.cat2, p.cat3, p.cat4, p.cat5
FROM org o
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT hd.org_id, d.cateogory, hd.score
    FROM Category d
    JOIN Assign hd ON d.catid=hd.catid
  )
  PIVOT (
    AVG(score)
    FOR (cateogory)
    IN ('cat1' as cat1, 'cat2' as cat2, 'cat3' as cat3, 'cat4' as cat4, 'cat5' as cat5)
  )
) p
ON p.org_id = o.org_id
ORDER BY o.org_id;
```

or more simply:

```
SELECT o.org_name, p.cat1, p.cat2, p.cat3, p.cat4, p.cat5
FROM (
  SELECT hd.org_id, d.cateogory, hd.score
  FROM Category d
  JOIN Assign hd ON d.catid=hd.catid
)
PIVOT (
  AVG(score)
  FOR (cateogory)
  IN ('cat1' as cat1, 'cat2' as cat2, 'cat3' as cat3, 'cat4' as cat4, 'cat5' as cat5)
) p
RIGHT JOIN org o
ON o.org_id = p.org_id
ORDER BY o.org_id;
```

which both get:

| ORG_NAME | CAT1 | CAT2 | CAT3 | CAT4 | CAT5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 99 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| CDE | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| FGH | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| Google | *null* | 12 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| Yahoo | *null* | 78 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| Facebook | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 98 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sIFRc-VY)

Your expected result seems to have the wrong values against the organisations (or the wrong IDs in the `org` table), but other than that, this seems to be your desired result.

Comment: I have a doubt here, Is it possible to include another text along with score in each column. For eg: if I have another field "color" in "Assign table" as column. so that that text also appear under pivot fields.

Comment: @Jeremy - yes, but as you're aggregating the `score` from that table, you'd need to either aggregate that other column as well (e.g. with `min`/`max`) or have one row per org/color.